# Copying recursively in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, copy

i have to get my fingers more on python, i didn't do much in python, so i don't really know how to start with this task.

I've already read some questions here on stack overflow, watched some yt-videos and also googled a ton, but i don't think, that there was one question similar to my task.

Lets say my directory looks like this:

The main folder is called "Test", it got 2 directories in it: 1 & 2.

Folder 1 also contains Folder 11, in which my file i have to copy is stored.

After going through these directories, it should go back to start"Test", opening Folder 2, no files are there, so its goes deeper into Folder 22, there are also no files, so it goes deeper again into Folder 23, where the last file is and it should copy this, to my destination folder.

Unfortunately i can't display my directories correctly, the List-formatting of stack overflow doesn't work for me idk.

I am working on Linux/Mac and python3 is used.

**code**

```py
#recursive copy method
import os
import shutil, errno

root_src_dir = '/Users/yolomir/OneDrive/OneDrive - ****'
root_dst_dir = '/Users/yolomir/OneDrive/OneDrive - ****'

for src_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_src_dir):
    dst_dir = src_dir.replace(root_src_dir, root_dst_dir, 1)
    if not os.path.exist(dst_dir):
        os.makedirs(dst_dir)
    for file_ in files:
        src_file = os.path.join(src_dir, file_)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dst_dir, file_)
        if os.path.exist(dst_file):
            os.remove(dst_file)
        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_dir)
```

Comment: What's your questions? And what have you tried to solve it already? *(We are not going to write all the code for you.)*

Comment: I am just asking how to get started with it. i already got some code, but it doesn't work
the **** stands for my company's name, i had to replace it.

Comment: Is it that you want the files copied directly into th destination folder without maintaining the structure of  the source directory?

Comment: i want to check step by step, if the folder is empty or not, if not empty, copy item to my destination folder and also check, if there is still another folder, if yes, go deeper and redo the function. But i don't know how exactly say in python, where my start point is etc. I only done scrapy before, but there i didn't have to use a lot of python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by myself and for all of you, that ever need a script, which checks your directories recursively and copy all files of a specific kind:

```py
from os import path
import shutil
import os
 
path = r"your/start/directory"
destination = r"your/destination/directory" 
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.yourfileextension' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
 
for file in files:
       if os.path.isfile(file):
           shutil.copy2(file, destination)
```